# Image upload through admin in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to be able to upload images through the admin in Django. But I am having some difficulty

project structure:

```
/Proj
   /Proj

   /static
      /img
         /albums
            /album1
               img1
            /album2
               img2
```

Album class:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Image class:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True, null = True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)  <-- !!!!
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank = True)
    albums = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I THINK my `image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)` uses the `get_upload_file_name` method to place the image in the correct album. This is done through appending to my `MEDIA_ROOT` which is `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

So the `get_upload_file_name` method is supposed to do so. But I am not sure how to so.

I think before I can upload I need to create an album first so then I can decide which album the image will go in. A bit lost at this point. Not sure if my `Image` or `Album` class is even complete. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass into `upload_to` must have the form:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    new_file_path_and_name = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'test.txt')
    return new_file_path_and_name
```

`instance` is the instance of the `Image` model you're about to save. That means it has access to all of the other fields that have been populated. `filename` is the original name of the file that was uploaded. You may choose to use `filename` or simply return another path + name of your choice.

The official documentation for this is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).